# Can I deploy a war file inside a built in/embed application server(like spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat, jive

I had been working on a project where I need to deploy a sample war file inside a built in/embed application server.

- Suppose for an example, I need to deploy sample.war file inside a
  spring boot application which has built in/embed tomcat server.

  or
- Deploy a sample.war file, inside a built in jive application which
  has a built in/embed tomcat application server.
  Note: As installed server has webapps or any other place to deploy.How is it possible to deploy a war if the server is of type jar/any other format ?

Comment: Yes, certainly - Tomcat is still Tomcat. You'll need to use a [`TomcatServletWebServerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.html).

Comment: Where should i place a new war file inside the spring boot/jive application ?

Comment: Wherever you wish. Must be accessible as a `File` - as of course it gets separately classloaded.

Comment: I didn't get you ? Is there any place in need to configure my war file.Suppose sample.war is my war file.Where in need to configure it ?